# Multiple random numbers in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to ask what is the best way to generate five UNIQUE random numbers (0-99).

I'm only familiar with generating a random number like this:

```
var randomizer = Random();

var num = randomizer.nextInt(100);
print(num);
```

Is there a way how to easily generate 5 different random numbers?

Comment: That is the best way of generating random numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simplest way to get five **unique** numbers from 100 is:

```
void main() {
  var list = List<int>.generate(100, (i) => i)..shuffle();
  list = list.take(5).toList();
  print(list);
}
```

we generate list with elements, then shuffle it and take first five elements

Answer (score 4):

If you meant to generate list of 5 random numbers.

You can

```
var randomizer = new Random();
var l = List.generate(5, (_) => randomizer.nextInt(100));
```